# Does $G=HK_1=HK_2$ imply $K_1=K_2$ in a locally cyclic group?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a locally cyclic group and $H,K_1,K_2\le G$ be subgroups such that $G=HK_1=HK_2$ and $H\cap K_1=H\cap K_2=\{1\}$.

Is $K_1=K_2$?

Comment: The answer seems to be positive according to Example 2.10. in this paper: http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/104834/ArchMath_010-1974-4_3.pdf

But I'm not sure.

Comment: Why do you think example 2.10 seems to support the claim in your question?

Comment: because subgroup lattice of a locally cyclic group is distributive. btw, I'm not sure if this is a correct deduction from the example.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G'$ be a finitely generated subgroup of $G$. Let $H'=H\cap G'$, $K_1' = G' \cap K_1$, and $K_2' = G' \cap K_2$. In a locally cyclic group the lattice of subgroups is distributive, hence

$$ G' = G' \cap HK_1 = (G' \cap H)(G'\cap K_1) = H'K_1',$$

and similarly $G'=H'K_2'$.

Now since $H\cap K = \{1\}$, we have $H' \cap K'=\{1\}$ and so $H'K_1' \simeq H' \times K_1'$ and similarly $H'K_2' \simeq H' \times K_2'$.

The groups $H'$, $K_1'$ and $K_2'$ are all cyclic, being subgroups of the cyclic group $G'$. Therefore we have

$$H_1 \simeq C_h, K_1' \simeq C_a, K_2' \simeq C_b,$$

for some integers $h$, $a$, $b$, where $C_n$ denotes the cyclic group of order $n$. Now from $H'K_1' = H'K_2'$ we get

$$ H' \times K_1' \simeq H' \times K_2' \Longrightarrow C_h \times C_a \simeq C_h \times C_b.$$

Comparing orders we obtain $a=b$, so that $K_1'$ is isomorphic to $K_2'$. Furthermore, since $G'\simeq C_h \times C_a$ is itself a cyclic group, necessarily $(h,a)=(h,b)=1$. It follows that any isomorphism $\phi: C_h \times C_a \rightarrow C_h \times C_a$ must restrict to isomorphisms $\phi_1: C_h \times \{1\} \rightarrow C_h \times \{1\}$ and $\phi_2: \{1\} \times C_a \rightarrow \{1\} \times C_b$. In particular, applying this to the identity map $H'K_1' \rightarrow H'K_2'$, we get $K_1' = K_2'$.

Now consider the filtered direct system $\{G_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in I}$ of all finitely generated subgroups of $G$. Then $G = \varinjlim G_\alpha$. For each $\alpha$ we have $G_\alpha \cap K_1 = G_\alpha \cap K_2$, so in the limit $K_1=K_2$.

Comment: I suggest to add "Yes" as the first word.

Comment: I have  a problem with $H_1 \simeq C_h, K_1' \simeq C_a, K_2' \simeq C_b$ .They may be infinite cyclic groups.

Comment: @user138171: Ah, let's see if it can be salvaged. I think the fact that $H' \times K_1'$ is also cyclic implies they must be finite. If they are both infinite, the direct product is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2$ and so not cyclic. If only one is infinite, the direct product is an infinite cyclic group, yet it has elements of finite order.

Comment: However, it may be that between $H'$ and $K_1'$ one group is infinite cyclic and the other is trivial. In that case $H'K_1' = H'K_2'$ still implies $K_1' = K_2'$.

Comment: thanks. you indirectly answered the question!

Comment: That's an excellent theorem in your own answer. And implies there was a much shorter proof. I hope my answer is correct, though it's clearly obsolete now. It was fun to think about anyway.

Comment: btw, the example in the paper linked above may provide another proof. But it needs a detailed examination.

Comment: We have $K_1 = K_1 \cap (H K_1) = K_1 \cap (H K_2) = (K_1 \cap H)(K_1 \cap K_2)=K_1 \cap K_2$, so $K_1 \subset K_2$. Similarly $K_2 \subset K_1$, therefore $K_1 = K_2$.

Answer (score 1):

As I was examining the question and the [other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/929535/138171) to the question, I remembered a theorem: the last part of theorem 5.1 in this book:

http://books.google.com/books?id=Ll0JXd11SW0C&pg=PA67#v=onepage&q&f=false

"$G=$" and "$=\{1\}$" in the question are unnecessary.